# Someone added an SSH key to my Github account

Tags: git, security, github, ssh

I just received an email saying "A new public key was added to your account". I checked my GitHub account and saw two keys - one was added by me several weeks ago from my Ubuntu machine, and one was added today from a Windows machine. This is a machine that I once worked on using GitHub client for Windows, but, I haven't entered it for several weeks now.

My questions are:

- Is it possible that another person got into that Windows machine and added a new public SSH key to my GitHub account?
- Does this mean that anyone entering that Windows machine can do actions on my behalf in GitHub?
- Besides deleting the new public key, how can I prevent people from adding new keys to my GitHub account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Yes. GitHub client stays logged in untill you manually logout/uninstall/revoke access. The client app adds SSH key to your account automatically when you are logged in.
- Yes.
- Delete the key and revoke GitHub client access to your account. You will find it on the website under Account settings>Applications>Authorized applications. The client application on the windows machine will require user login once again to regain access to your account.

Comment: Can a new key be generated using GitHub on a new machine, without knowing about it? I have a fresh Win 10 Pro machine (same machine, new RAM and SSDs), and during installing everything I received an email saying "[GitHub] A new public key was added to your account" and "The following SSH key was added to your account", however I only logged into the GitHub website and created issues. Nothing more. I also see the creation was from my desktop, as the machine name matches. It was 4 hours ago. (Am I compromised?) My first use of GitHub for Windows, installing and doing a commit, was an hour ago.

Answer (score 4):

There was an [attack on GitHub recently](https://github.com/blog/1698-weak-passwords-brute-forced) and they've taken some measures, so the new key can be the attackers' one or it can be set by github (I can't say). The best you can do is remove your keys and passwords and replace them with new one immediately.